# Pipe Command To PowerShell from Shell Script

Tags: powershell

I have some Windbg script where I can call out to a cmd shell via the .shell command. Now I want to execute some Windbg command and pipe the output to the shell script which should start powershell.exe to process the input data. 
So far I did fail.

In principle it should be possible to pass data from stdin to powershell pipes?

```
echo C: | powershell.exe -Command "| dir"
```

I do not want to create an extra powershell script because that would complicate the windbg script further and create external dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the predefined `$input` variable to use the text you echo into powershell. In conjunction with the pipeline, this works perfectly:

```
echo C:\ | powershell.exe -command "$input | dir"
```

Edit: You also need to use `echo C:\`. I'm not sure of the reasoning, but simply writing `Get-ChildItem 'C:'` defaults to the current directory.

Comment: Thanks. $input was the missing piece!

Comment: Re `c:` vs. `c:\ `: a mere drive spec. always refers to the current directory _on that drive_.